# How to use terraform to deploy a Google Cloud Run service from source?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm currently deploying a Cloud Run service using the following command line:

```
gcloud run deploy webserver --source webserver/ --other-flags...
```

The Terraform configuration for Cloud Functions could build from a `.zip` in a `google_storage_bucket_object` using the [source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function#nested_source) block, but the [`cloud_run_service` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service) doesn't have a similar block.

The `gcloud run deploy --source` command reports that it's equivalent to `gcloud builds submit --pack image=[IMAGE] webserver/` and `gcloud run deploy webserver --image [IMAGE]`, but the [Cloud Build resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger) don't appear to allow submitting builds at all.

What's the simplest way to translate this `gcloud run deploy --source` command to Terraform?

Comment: Why running a gcloud command with terraform? In your CI/CD, if you already have something that create a zip, you can invoke something to create a container (docker build for instance). From there, provide the newly created container to your terraform config and let terraform deploying the container only. Don't provide the responsibility to build the container to terraform, keep the separation of dutty.

Comment: I'm deploying from the command line, not from CI. For a fully-mature project, of course CI would be better, but this project is too small and not critical enough to be worth the overhead.

If you look at the command lines, you'll also see that this is using buildpacks rather than Docker directly.

Terraform itself has a way to create a .zip (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file), so it's not even the case that creating files is outside Terraform's reasonable use cases.

Comment: You can do anything with terraform, that's not the tool problem, it's more a design issue. Use IaC tool for infra and deployment, not for building and packaging!